# Max offsets in each Micro Batch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming executing in the default trigger. My goal is to limit the volume read in each of these executions to avoid a huge micro batch. Sometimes my Spark Jobs stop the whole weekend, so when I restart them, they take so long to finish the first one. I also persist the Dataframes 'cause this is written in 2 databases. Two approaches were tested.

Official docs says that **maxOffsetsPerTrigger** limit the number of offsets processed per trigger interval, but that did not work for me. Did I misunderstood the meaning of this param?

```
  val read = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServers)
  .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "1")
  .load()
```

Also, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612213/how-does-the-default-unspecified-trigger-determine-the-size-of-micro-batches-i) answer, but I do not know where and how to set **max.poll.records** correctly. I tried in the option of the readStream with no success. Code below:

```
  val read = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServers)
  .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .option("max.poll.records", "1")
  .load()
```

Main function:

```
override def execute(spark: SparkSession, args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val basePath: String = args(0)
    val kafkaServers: String = args(1)
    val kafkaTopic: String = args(2)
    val checkpoint: String = args(3)

    val read = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServers)
      .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "1")
      .load()

    val transformed = read
      .transform(applySchema)
      .transform(conversions)
      .transform(dropDuplicates)
      .transform(partitioning)

    val sink = new FileSystemSink(basePath)

    val query = transformed
      .writeStream
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
      .foreachBatch(sink.writeOnS3 _)
      .option("checkpointLocation", f"$basePath/checkpoints/$checkpoint")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }
```

**Besides the questions above, what is the correct way to limit offsets?**

*Spark Version: 2.4.5.*

Comment: The configuration `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` works fine for me and you have the right understanding of it. `max.poll.records` is for plain KafkaConsumers, not for Spark Structured Streaming. Can you show full code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sure, I can. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I think there is nothing different :/

Comment: The value set on maxOffsetsPerTrigger is per partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested again and **maxOffsetsPerTrigger** worked just fine. I misunderstood the result of the trigger and now it makes sense. The param means the total offsets read, not the offsets per partition.