# Spark job writing to parquet - has a container with physical memory that keeps increasing

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a spark streaming application that reads from kafka topic and writes the data to hdfs in parquet format.
I see that during time(very short time) the physical memory of the container keeps growing until it reaches the maximum size and fails on 
"Diagnostics: Container [pid=29328,containerID=container_e42_1512395822750_0026_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.3 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container."
The container that is being killed is the same that runs the driver so the application is also being killed.
When looking for this error I only saw solutions of increasing the memory but this I think will only postpone the problem.
I want to understand why is the memory keeps increasing if I don't save anything in memory.
I also saw that all containers have increases in memory but they are just being killed after a while(before reaching the maximum).
I saw in some post "Your job is writing out Parquet data, and Parquet buffers data in memory prior to writing it out to disk".

The code we are using (we also tried without the repartition - not sure that is needed):

```
val repartition = rdd.repartition(6)
val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(repartition)
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(dbLocation)
```

Is there some way to just fix the increasing memory problem ?

The created parquet files
[image: The created parquet files]

The nodeManager logs that show the increase in the memory
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming your application does nothing other than just writes, I suspect the root cause to be size of data being received in batches. It's possible that data received in one of the batches is beyond the thresholds configured. Assuming the application is killed for this season, the solution is to enable "**back pressure**".
The solution is detailed enough in the post below.*

[Limit Kafka batches size when using Spark Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981650/limit-kafka-batches-size-when-using-spark-streaming)

Comment: The memory isn't increased at one time ,just keeps in rising with time , so it seems like the data is really cached but isn't deleted by the garbage collector .  Our application dies after 9 hours at least

Comment: Do you use any transformations like unions or update by key in the data pipeline?

Comment: Does your code write any parquet file in the destination at all? Do you know whether the pervious batch's files gets saved before the next batch's processing starts? It appears to me that the data from multiple batches gets queued up in driver to be written to HDFS folder. Are you reading the Kafka stream from the latest batch or are you reading  the entire stream?

Comment: We are reading from kafka in batches of 2 minutes so assume the previous batch was already written to HDFS but will check for sure. I am reading each time only the new messages from kafka(using the kafka stream of spark)

Comment: I added screen shots of the created parquet files and the data manager log

Comment: by the way the problematic container is running both the driver and an executor, all other executors are being killed when they get to some heap size(about 800MB)