# Limit kafka batch size when using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

We have some historical data queued up on our topics, we don't want to process all this data in a single batch as that is harder to do (and if it fails it has to start again!).

Also, knowing how to control the batch size would be quite helpful in tuning jobs.

When using `DStreams` the way to control the size of the batch as exactly as possible is [Limit Kafka batches size when using Spark Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981650/limit-kafka-batches-size-when-using-spark-streaming/46156603#46156603)

The same approach i.e. setting `maxRatePerPartition` and then tuning `batchDuration` is extremely cumbersome but works with `DStream` it doesn't work at all with Structured Streaming.

Ideally I'd like to know of a config like `maxBatchSize` and `minBatchSize`, where I can simply set the number of records I'd like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This config option[`maxOffsetsPerTrigger`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

> Rate limit on maximum number of offsets processed per trigger interval. The specified total number of offsets will be proportionally split across topicPartitions of different volume.

**Note** that if you have a checkpoint directory with start and end offsets, then the application will process the offsets in the directory for the first batch, thus ignoring this config. (The next batch will respect it).

Comment: Will this throttle my job?  What exactly is a trigger interval?  Will it read from Kafka as quickly as possible, but just limit the number of records read?

Comment: Can use this instead, and handle offsets yourself, which will be more predictable/flexible than StructureStreaming. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53065951/1586965

Comment: @samthebest This works well to limit `batchSize`. What option shall be used to limit/control `trigger-frequency`? (Something similar to `Duration.class` in Spark Streaming).

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ Concept you're looking for is [trigger](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers), specifically _Fixed interval micro-batches_.

Answer (score 0):

If the topic is partitioned and all the partitions has messages, the minimum messages you can take is equal to the number of partitions in the topic. (ie) it takes 1 record per partition if it has data, if only one partition has data then the minimum record you can take is 1. If the topic is not partitioned you can take 1 record minimum and anything as maximum.